# Accessing view_context in Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Within a model I have the following method:

```
def some_method
  some_obj.new(view_c: view_context).create_some_links
end
```

An exception is thrown with the following message:

> undefined local variable or method `view_context'

I am fully aware that it is not good practice to call view-related methods from your model, but nonetheless: Is it possible to access `view_context` from the model so that I can pass it along to a Plain Old Ruby Object (PORO) which creates some links?

**Update**: From the code I have above, one suggestion might be to simply create and call the PORO directly in the view.  However: pretend that the code requires it to go through the model in order to create the right PORO.

[view_context doc](https://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Rendering/view_context)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you pass the `view_context` to the method it *is impossible*:

- model layer has nothing to do with view layer.
- model itself can not possibly know anything about view context.
- model has no access to view context.

---

Here's how you'd pass a view to the method (while being in the view):

```
@model_instance.some_method(self) # self is the view itself
```

Now, slight method change does the trick:

```
def some_method(view_context)
  some_obj.new(view_c: view_context).create_some_links
end
```